# Is null > 0 (integer)

Tags: sql, null

If I have in my sql something like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOMETABLE 
WHERE ((SELECT ONECOLUMN FROM ANOTHERTABLE WHERE ID = 42) > 0)
```

If I got a NULL in `ONECOLUMN` it will be greater then 0?

Comment: This is something you can try on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As NULL means "not known", NULL is not greater than 0. It's not smaller either. It's not known. Hence `NULL > 0` results in NULL, rather than in TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is not greater than zero.
NULL is not equal to zero.
NULL is not less than zero.

Any given integer you might choose would meet exactly one of these three conditions.  But not NULL.

NULL isn't an integer.  It's a marker indicating that a value is not present.  This could mean that a value exists, but is unknown.  It could also indicate that no value exists in this context.

You can use the ISNULL function to find out whether a NULL is present instead of a value.  But if you compare a value with zero,  and there is a NULL in place of the value,  you won't get either TRUE or FALSE as a result.

If you are confused, you're in good company.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking for `NULL` and then returning `0` if true otherwise return the value of `ONECOLUMN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOMETABLE 
WHERE (
  SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(ONECOLUMN) THEN 0 ELSE ONECOLUMN END 
  FROM ANOTHERTABLE 
  WHERE ID = 42
) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Null is unknown and it cannot be compared to any value. It cannot be greater or lesser.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    FROM SOMETABLE
    WHERE (
        IsNull((SELECT ONECOLUMN
            FROM ANOTHERTABLE
            WHERE ID = 42), IntValue) > 0
          )
```

If you need to accept the `Null` so `IntValue` can be `1` otherwise `-1` is OK.